# Using regex to get mouse MAC address

Tags: regular-expression

What would be the most handy way to grab the mouse's mac address from the following output:

```
~ ➜ bt-device --list
Added devices:
Logitech K811 (00:1F:20:EB:06:E0)
Plattan ADV Wireless (5C:EB:68:1F:D1:62)
Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535 (34:88:5D:3F:1B:88)
```

Is there something shorter than this:

```
bt-device --list | grep Mouse | sed -e 's/^.*(\(.*\))$/\1/'
34:88:5D:3F:1B:88
```

I'm looking for a syntax like:

```
bt-device --list | grep Mouse | xyztool '(' ')'
```

Comment: Remove the grep and yours is as good a choice as the others.      bt-device --list | sed -e 's/^.*Mouse.*(\(.*\))$/\1/' you could set this as an alias or function in .bashrc if you use it frequently; or just export the regex as an env variable - thats pretty common for regexs for IP addresses, urls, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use awk to match the line and split it into words separated by `(` or `)`. Take the 2nd word `$2`, or preferably the next-to-last `$(NF-1)` if you might have parentheses in the device name:

```
awk -F '[()]' '/Mouse/{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: @Jander That's a good point. I've updated the answer. thanks.

Comment: @TomFenech oops. I should have copied my test script instead of just editing the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
bt-device --list | grep -Po 'Mouse\s.*?\(\K[^)]+'
```

- `Mouse\s.*?\(` will match `Mouse` in the line and then upto first `(`, `\K` will discard the match
- `[^)]+` will get us the desired portion i.e. characters upto the next `)`

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
Added devices:
Logitech K811 (00:1F:20:EB:06:E0)
Plattan ADV Wireless (5C:EB:68:1F:D1:62)
Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535 (34:88:5D:3F:1B:88)

$ grep -Po 'Mouse\s.*?\(\K[^)]+' file.txt
34:88:5D:3F:1B:88
```

Answer (score 0):

A few more choices:

1. Perl

   ```
   $ bt-device --list | perl -lne 'print $1 if /Mouse.*\((.*)\)/' file 
   34:88:5D:3F:1B:88
   ```

   In many tools that deal with regular expressions, parentheses (`()`) are used to capture the matched pattern in a way that can later be used. In Perl, the 1st such captured pattern is `$1`, the second `$2` etc. Here, we are looking for a line that matches `Mouse` and then a string in parentheses. The contents of the parentheses are saved as `$1` and are printed if the match was successful.
2. grep + cut + tr

   ```
   $ bt-device --list grep Mouse | cut -d'(' -f2 | tr -d ')'
   34:88:5D:3F:1B:88
   ```

   Here, we use `grep` to find the relevant line(s), `cut` to print the second `(`-defined field (`34:88:5D:3F:1B:88)`) and `tr` to delete the trailing `)`.
3. Just for fun, here's a solution with `join`:

   ```
   $ join -1 1 -2 2 -o 2.4 <(echo "Mouse (") <(bt-device --list) 2>/dev/null | tr -d '()'
   34:88:5D:3F:1B:88
   ```